# How can I open with VBA a attachment of excel file and verify inside the file before seva the message in a determined folder in outlook?

Tags: vba, outlook

I receive determined e-mails with an attached excel file and I need to know if this email is part of a process before moving it to a determined folder.

1. The macro starts when an email arrives.
2. The macro verifies if the email has an excel attachment.
3. If it's an Excel file, the macro verifies if inside the file the first cell contains the word "process".
4. If that is true, the macro moves the email to a determined folder in Outlook.

I can do the first and second step, but I don't know if it's possble to open a excel file attachment and verify the first cell.

Comment: Have you done anything yet?

Comment: Please show us your code. If all you want to know is, if it's possible to check for the word "process": yes, it is. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Called from a rule.

```
Sub TEST1(o As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim xl As Excel.Application

    If InStr(1, o.Attachments(1), ".xls") > 0 Then

        Set xl = New Excel.Application
        xl.Visible = 1
        '    Save the attachment here as strAttachmentName
        xl.Workbooks.Open strAttachmentName
        If xl.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").Value = "Processing" Then
            o.Move Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Workbooks.Open takes a file name, not an instance of the Outlook.Attachment object. Save the attachment to a file (Attachment.SaveAsFile), then pass the file name to Workbooks.Open

Comment: referencing it like that returns the file name of the attachment, although it is technically the attachment object, the return is Filename.xlsx

Comment: FileName happens to be the default property, so it gets returned when a string is necessary to pass to a string parameter. But the important thing is that the file with that name does not exist anywhere on the file system, and Open will raise an exception.

Comment: Yes, with the opening, unless the attachment is on a share :)

Comment: @Dmitry Streblechenko, I've altered now :)

Comment: Your code still needs to call Attachment.SaveAsFile.

Comment: Also, the line `If InStr(1, o.Attachments(1), ".xls") > 0 Then` needs to be changed to `If InStr(1, o.Attachments(1).FileName, ".xls") > 0 Then`. You also need to loop through all attachments, your code expects the messages to have a single Excel file attachment.